# Check Rotated Rectangle hit Point with Fixed shape Rectangle in HTML5 + Javascript and Canvas

Tags: rotation, html5-canvas, rectangles, hit

Hi, I am making a car game where I draw a car shape Rectangle as follows. xP and yP is coming dynamically from the keyboard event in JavaScript and so is the rotation.

```
ctxDrift.clearRect(0, 0, 426, 754);
ctxDrift.save();
ctxDrift.beginPath();
ctxDrift.translate(xP-car.getWidth()/2, yP-car.getHeight()/2);
ctxDrift.rotate((Math.PI / 180) * car.getRotation());
ctxDrift.translate(-xP, -yP);
ctxDrift.rect(xP-car.getWidth()/2, yP-car.getHeight()/2, car.getWidth(), car.getHeight());
ctxDrift.fillStyle = 'yellow';
ctxDrift.fill();
ctxDrift.restore();
```

Now there are some obstacles, with Rectangle shape, which are not rotated. Now how could I check the hit between these 2 objects. Or say how to check the rectangle points lies inside another rectangle, if rotated?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to rotate the rectangle bounding boxes, so they are essentially no longer rotated, before you do the collision check. Then rotate them back before the image is drawn.

Even better, have a bounding box that doesn't rotate which can be used for broad-phase testing (a quick and cheap check to see if you need to then do a narrow-phase check).

This is known as an **axis-aligned bounding box**, or AABB for short. This greatly simplifies your collision detection code.

*update:* Found [this link](http://www.gamefromscratch.com/post/2012/11/26/GameDev-math-recipes-Collision-detection-using-an-axis-aligned-bounding-box.aspx) that might be useful.

Answer (score 1):

*Even before you even get started with collision testing:*
Canvas does not track where your objects are on the canvas. **You** must manually keep track of the accumulated .translate() and .rotate() done by the user.  You do this by capturing the transformation matrix changes for each user keyboard event.  Then you accumulate the transforms into one final transformation matrix that you can use to *start* hit testing.

From there, the math on collision testing gets quickly complicated!

Your simplest collisiion test is simply to surround each rectangle with a circle and then calculate whether the circle centerpoints are within the sum of the 2 circle radii. The code looks like this:

```
function CirclesCollide(x1,y1,radius1,x2,y2,radius2){
    return ( Math.sqrt( ( x2-x1 ) * ( x2-x1 )  + ( y2-y1 ) * ( y2-y1 ) ) < ( radius1 + radius2 ) );
}
```

If you want better collision testing and you're willing to wade through **LOTS** of math, here is a good source of 3 collision tests:  http://www.sfml-dev.org/wiki/en/sources/simple_collision_detection

Perhaps the best solution is to use a canvas library like FabricJs which tracks where your objects are on the canvas and provides the hit-testing for you.  Easy as this!

```
var theyAreColliding = myCar.intersectsWithObject(myObstical);
```

Comment: Circle collision detection is rather slow. Doing this kind of test is obviously only good for doing a broad phase (rough) collision check - but then why not keep the maths simple (and quick) and use a AABB rectangle?

Comment: @Jarrod: Umm…circle collision is **fast** ( just 1 Math.sqrt and some +-*) and **simple** (just 1 line of code!).  I agree it’s a rough collision test, but it’s simple for the OP to start with. Since the car’s longer side will mostly be going forward, the inaccuracy of the circle is minimized (min space between rect and circle).   Notice that I did go on to suggest some “better” tests…including your AABB—but these cost MUCH more code, math & cpu cycles!  Also, the AABB boundingbox becomes square at 45,135,225,315 degrees—almost as inaccurate as circle! BTW, I like & use AABB! It's just costly!

Comment: `Math.sqrt` is very costly. Look it up.

Comment: @VarunJi--Hope we helped with your question......@Jarrod--I'm not into flame wars, but I stand by my answer and comments--I'm done.

Comment: Sorry for the delay response. But Thanks to both of you...  i think AABB is the best way for me, because i can take any shape (in rectangle) for this. And Yes Circle is very simple to check. But circle with Rectangle needs lots of coding

Comment: This is what i am looking for :) 
http://www.rgraph.net/blog/2012/october/new-html5-canvas-features.html

Answer (score 1):

This is what i am looking for this Query

http://www.rgraph.net/blog/2012/october/new-html5-canvas-features.html

canvas have now addHitRegion() function, where we can track easily for this.

New One and best

http://www.playmycode.com/blog/2011/08/javascript-per-pixel-html5-canvas-image-collision-detection/

Answer (score 0):

I have finally added my own logic, which is here

http://jslogic.blogspot.in/2013/02/javascript-bound-rectangle-area-while.html